# PowerShell raw FTP

Tags: powershell, ftp, mainframe, jcl

I am looking to use FTP to write a mainframe jobstream. To do that, I can connect to the mainframe via FTP and run these commands:

```
QUOTE TYPE E
QUOTE SITE FILETYPE=JES
PUT myjob.jcl
```

So, how would I do this in PowerShell? I have read plenty on standard FTP transfers, but I haven't seen anything about customizing the calls for prep.

Thanks for reading.

**EDIT**

Here is the solution I came up with, per the answer here and [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/how-to-automate-ftp-uploads-from-the-windows-command-line/):

```
@echo off
echo user %1> ftpcmd.dat
echo %2>> ftpcmd.dat
echo QUOTE TYPE E>> ftpcmd.dat
echo QUOTE SITE FILETYPE=JES>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put %3>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat %4
del ftpcmd.dat
```

Usage:

```
C:\>fileup user123 pa$$word myfile.txt ftp.server.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you use the -s switch for FTP and specify a file that contains your commands to run?

```
  -s:filename     Specifies a text file containing FTP commands; the
                  commands will automatically run after FTP starts.
```

Then you can call this in PowerShell as

```
ftp -s:<myscript> <host>
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. I actually created a .bat file to handle this. See my edit for the solution I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with .NET and want to do it programatically, there is a similar question/answer here:

[Upload files with FTP using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1867385/4916)

It pretty much goes comes down to using a `System.Net.FtpWebRequest` for the job. At first glance it seems fairly straight forward.

Comment: Scott, I appreciate your feedback, but System.Net.FtpWebRequest does not have room for "arbitrary" calls. The QUOTE TYPE E and QUOTE SITE FILETYPE=JES are not supported via FtpWebRequest.