# How do i FTP upload directory in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I came across this post:
[Upload files with FTP using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867385/upload-files-with-ftp-using-powershell)

But I'm looking  how i can upload a directory with files in it to a FTP server.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a script that loop into directory and then upload files one by one. I don't remember that ftp command on windows can upload an entire directory.

You should find example  here :

http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsFtpBatchScript.php