# Windows Command Line FTP to deploy website

Tags: windows, command-line, ftp, cmd, powershell-2.0

Trying to set up a post build script on my CI server to push changes to our web server by FTP.  In as few lines as possible how can i push a folder of files to my webserver using windows FTP?  For example deployment folder is:

```
c:\deployment\*.*
```

How can i recursively push all files to replace on the web server?

I'm open to using cmd or powershell - MS Windows only

Thanks

Comment: Why does it have to be "in as few lines as possible" if it's a script? LOC should not matter much - what counts is the *results*. I much prefer a longer, slightly more verbose script that's easily understood by anyone picking it up vs. 2 densely-packed lines full of arcane commands which require reading additional documentation to understand.

Comment: See [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867385/upload-files-with-ftp-using-powershell) asking for the same thing in PowerShell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows' built-in command-line FTP client doesn't have recursion built-in.  The easiest way would be to use a different FTP client.  [NcFTP](http://www.ncftp.com/download/) will do what you're looking for.  See the [manual page for ncftpput](http://www.ncftpd.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpput.html).  The syntax is basically as follows:

```
cd c:\deployment
ncftpput -u user -p pass -R ftp.ftpserver.com /path/on/ftp/server .\*
```

Or if your web server also runs an ssh service, then `rsync` would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

[Fsync is good](http://www.eternitysoftware.com), I am using it for long. It allows to push only what has changed. Recursion of course. Exclude files, too. Track client-side (much faster) what has changed... Biggest only drawback: No SFTP./ProductList/Fsync.html