# Upload images on FTP Server using Powershell

Tags: powershell, ftp

I want to use powershell script to upload images on FTP server but I keep getting error An exception occurred during a WebClient request, not sure what's wrong with my script. Any help please?

```
$FTPHost = "ftp://xxxx/"
$FTPUser = "xxxx"
$FTPPass = "xxxxx"

$source = "C:\Images"

$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($FTPUser, $FTPPass)

$files = get-childitem $source -recurse -force

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    Write-Host "Uploading $file"
    $webClient.UploadFile("$FTPHost", $file.Name)
}

$webClient.Dspose()
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: [Check this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867385/upload-files-with-ftp-using-powershell/55851496#55851496) "Upload files with FTP using PowerShell" it's the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `UploadFile` this way:

```
$webClient.UploadFile("$FTPHost" + "/" + $file.Name, "STOR", $file.FullName)
```

You have to give it the full filename and also where to store it.

Comment: I just tried that and got a new error                                                    Exception calling "UploadFile" with "3" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)."
At C:\FTPImages.ps1:24 char:5
+     $webClient.UploadFile("$uri" + "/" + $file.Name, "STOR", $file.FullName)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

Comment: Peter your suggestion actually worked. There was an extra slash causing the issue. .... thanks