# Upload files using FTP in PowerShell Scripts Fail

Tags: powershell, ftp, webclient, webexception

I am using PowerShell Scripts to upload the files by FTP. The scripts I use is following:

```
$File = "C:\test\test01.txt"
$ftp = "ftp://MyUsername:MyPassword@MyHostName/"

"ftp url: $ftp"

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)

"Uploading $File..."

$webclient.UploadFile($uri,$File)
```

But When I run the scripts, I get the following errors:

```
 Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command."
At C:\FTP.ps1:11 char:1
+ $webclient.UploadFile($uri,$File)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

The Powershell Version I use is following:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      0      -1     -1
```

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a third parameter, e.g. `"fred"` as the name to save the file as on the server?

Answer (score 0):

A possible explenation could be that your username/password contains special characters that are not allowed in a valid URI (such as `@` or `:`).

Instead you should set your credentials using [`System.Net.NetworkCredential`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential(v=vs.110).aspx)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1868367/4569506) for reference