# FTP transfer code fails with "[System.IO.FileStream] doesn't contain a method named "CopyTo""

Tags: .net, powershell, stream, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I'm trying a code from:
[Upload files with FTP using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1867385/850848#46582183)

```
$request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip")
$request.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
$request.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile 

$fileStream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead("C:\local\path\file.zip")
$ftpStream = $request.GetRequestStream()

$fileStream.CopyTo($ftpStream)

$ftpStream.Dispose()
$fileStream.Dispose()
```

And I get this error:

> Error in Calling this method:  [System.IO.FileStream] doesn't contain a method named "CopyTo".

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

For [`Stream.CopyTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto), you need .NET framework 4.

- Either upgrade your .NET framework installation
- Or use a loop, as you can see in the *"Progress monitoring"* section of my answer to:
  [Upload files with FTP using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1867385/850848#46582183)

  ```
  $buffer = New-Object Byte[] 10240
  while (($read = $fileStream.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)) -gt 0)
  {
      $ftpStream.Write($buffer, 0, $read)
  }
  ```