# How to use passwordless prompt in Powershell for sftp

Tags: powershell, exe, sftp

This is my command that I'm trying to connect to my server from Powershell:

```
$mysftp = @"
$(sftp -P2222 non-root-user@myserver.icom
"SomeRandomPass"
lcd C:\Users\Saeed\Desktop\test
cd /etc/
get hostname
bye)
"@
$mysftp
```

There are two issues:

1. It asks again for my password
2. It only connects to sftp but doesn't do anything.
3. When I run `$mysftp`, it only prints the values of this variable, but doesn't execute that.

- The user is not `root`, so I cannot change `sshd_config` to use keys to connect.

How can I connect to sftp and do my commands with no password in Powershell?

My Powershell version is `PSVersion 5.1.19041.3031`.

Comment: `sftp.exe` is an external command and not directly related to PowerShell itself. If you want to use PowerShell, you would be better of with directly invoking `.Net` classes. See e.g.: [Upload files with FTP using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1868367/1701026)