# Publish to FTP after TFS 2010 build quality change

Tags: tfs, build

When I change the quality of a build in TFS 2010 (to production quality), I would like to have the build uploaded to my FTP site on a remote server.

Are there any tools you know of that can accomplish this? If not, any suggestions on how I can do this myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to automate this you probably need to use the notification system in TFS. You would need to build a web service that receives the notification from TFS and then have that web service do the FTP upload or make it queue a new build that would do the FTP upload. I would probably go for the second alternative so I could easily do the upload manually if needed.

You can read more about the event service here:

[Team Foundation Server Event Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507647.aspx)

Comment: This is the pre 2010 way of doing it. TFS2010 now has a plugin system that allows you to write classes that inherit from ISubscriber without having to post SOAP messages to an external webservice.

Answer (score 5):

TFSDeployer might be useful, the build quality change event triggers the execution of a configured powershell script depending on the build quality.

http://tfsdeployer.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could use Powershell in a post-build step: [What’s the best way to automate secure FTP in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265339/whats-the-best-way-to-automate-secure-ftp-in-powershell)