# How can I deploy from the drop location given a specific build number using TFS

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration, msdeploy

Trying to implement CI using TFS.  I have the builds working fine and the projects are all nicely split up in the drop folder.  My question is, how can I allow the QA team queue up a deployment "build" (no actual building going on) where they can give a specific build number.  This build number is then used to deploy the bits in that specific build drop folder.

The ultimate goal is to give them a couple of parameters on the queue build dialog (done that already) and then start the deployment process.  I thought of using TFS Deployer, tried creating my own deployment process template and then executing a powershell script from the .proj file.  Seems like each option has it's own set of complications.

Can anyone give me some guidance on the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio and TFS? What kind of deployments?

Comment: TFS 2010 and we're deploying windows services, web services and web applications.  Also, there are no direct connections between the build server and the staging server, so everything has to be FTP'd.  I have PowerShell scripts already done to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently using the following:

1. Select the deployment target (selects machine, site, multiple configuration item data).
2. Custom .config file transformations to match deployment target (connection strings etc.).
3. Exec task for MSDeploy to get the build to the server using Web Deploy 2.0.
4. PSExec executing an appcmd command remotely on the server to restart the specific site
5. Repeat for services, push with MSDeploy.
6. Build script generates install/uninstall scripts for services.
7. PSExec for services (stop, uninstall, install, start).

This was kept isolated in an MSBuild file, which can be executed from any command line passing in the build drop number, or can be added to the TFS build definition with an MSBuild task, keyed off of the extra parameters you've already set up.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to trigger the deployment on a change in build quality. The idea is that when the quality is changed to "Ready for QA" for instance, a change event triggers to deploy from the existing build folders to the QA system.

See [Publish to FTP after TFS 2010 build quality change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960388/publish-to-ftp-after-tfs-2010-build-quality-change) and [Auto-Deployment Using Microsoft Web Deploy on Build Quality Change Event of TFS 2010](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/TFS2010BuildAutoDeploymen.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the users who have permissions to kick off a build and through this give the rights to kick off a manual build to your QA team.

In your TFS build script you can create the deployment steps needed for your QA team. By default you would make it conditional based on a parameter and have it set to not deploy. You could make this true or false depending on if it is a CI build or a manual build.

When you are ready to have your code tested by QA you give them the label to use and they would just have to pass it in and would be able to build and deploy it.

The beauty of this is you control which signed off version of code you are ready to hand off to your QA team.

You also have a report that lists the specific code and work items that were handed off to QA.