# Powershell, ftp, get-childitem

Tags: powershell, ftp, get-childitem

Little new to powershell.  I am trying to locate a get-childitem like command that will work on an ftp site.

Here is some psuedo-code:

```
$target = "c:\file.txt"
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
$ftp = "ftp://$username:$password@myftpsite"

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp) 

#below is the code that does not work, get-childitem needs a local path
$name = get-childitem -path $ftp
```

The get-childitem only works with a local path.  Does anyone know how I could access the filenames in this manner when on an ftp site?

Thanks

Comment: The answers here might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265339

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would need is a PowerShell provider for FTP if you wanted Get-ChildItem to work on a remote filesystem accessed by FTP.  This [forum post](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/20526-provider-resolution.html) mentions work being done by Nick Howell on an FTP provider.  Other than that, I haven't heard of any other FTP providers for PowerShell.