# Powershell method to SFTP to Linux

Tags: powershell-remoting

Is there any Powershell script to do SFTP to a Unix/Linux machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265339/whats-the-best-way-to-automate-secure-ftp-in-powershell

Comment: The question is not a duplicate. The SFTP discussed there was about FTP or FTP with SSL. But FTP is not SFTP and SSL is not SSH. Anyone you tried SFTP in .NET ?

Comment: There is such a script because I wrote one recently. I used WinSCP as SFTP client though, so not sure if this is what you are looking for. WinSCP is highly scriptable and even has .NET/COM libraries (http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell#example). That said, my own script simply built a command file, passed it to WinSCP then checked result codes, output and logs for errors so it's fairly simple stuff.