# powershell ftp upload issues

Tags: powershell, ftp

Okay Im not sure what the problem is but I've been all over the internet and cannot get this to work! Im trying to do a simple upload of a 4 byte text file to a ftp serer. I took the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265339/whats-the-best-way-to-automate-secure-ftp-in-powershell) exactly and put in the file i wanted to upload and the server password and username. But every time i wait and it eventually sends me this error:

Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."
At \hqpublic\public\EMSDropBox\test2.ps1:22 char:39
+ $ftpresponse = $ftprequest.GetResponse <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The only thing I can think off the bat to try is to add `$ftprequest.UsePassive = $false`, it will turn passive mode off.

Comment: .....you know i have spent 4 hours changing every property and trying every combination of code but never that...... thank you

Comment: Did it solve your problem? In that case, I'll add it as an answer so it may help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think off the bat to try is to add `$ftprequest.UsePassive = $false`.

It will turn passive mode off and will fix connection issues that are usually caused by the FTP server being behind a firewall without FTP connection tracking.