# Changing FTP from binary to ascii in PowerShell script using WebClient

Tags: .net, powershell, ftp, webclient

Simple PowerShell script. It downloads a file (in binary) with no issues. I need it in ascii.

```powershell
$File = "c:\temp\ftpfile.txt"
$ftp = "ftp://myusername:mypass@12.345.6.78/'report'";
$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient;
$uri = New-Object -TypeName System.Uri -ArgumentList $ftp;
$webclient.DownloadFile($uri, $File);
```

Comment: Is the file in ascii at the source?  Is it in Unicode?  Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebClient` does not support ascii/text FTP mode.

Use [`FtpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest) instead and set [`.UseBinary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.usebinary) to false.

```powershell
$File = "c:\temp\ftpfile.txt"
$ftp = "ftp://myusername:mypass@12.345.6.78/'report'";

$ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($ftp)

$ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::DownloadFile
$ftprequest.UseBinary = $false

$ftpresponse = $ftprequest.GetResponse()

$responsestream = $ftpresponse.GetResponseStream()

$targetfile = New-Object IO.FileStream($File, [IO.FileMode]::Create)

$responsestream.CopyTo($targetfile)

$targetfile.close()
```

Reference: [What's the best way to automate secure FTP in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/265339/850848)

---

Note that the `WebClient` uses the `FtpWebRequest` internally, but does not expose its `.UseBinary` property.