# When replacing deprecated FtpWebRequest with WebClient, how to use ascii mode?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, webclient, ftpwebrequest

If I understand well, `FtpWebRequest` is disadvised by MS in favor of `WebClient`. But while uploading with `Webclient` I do not seem to be able to switch off binary mode. I get double linefeeds. How to prevent this with `WebClient` or is it better to switch to `FtpWebRequest`? How to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebClient` uses `(Ftp)WebRequest` internally. So it is as deprecated as `(Ftp)WebRequest`.

The [documentation of `WebClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient) contains a similar notice as `(Ftp)WebRequest`:

> We don't recommend that you use the `WebClient` class for new development. Instead, use the [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) class.

*(disregarding the fact that the notice is about HTTP and not FTP)*

---

That makes your question about CRLF pointless. – Either you are happy with using deprecated class, and then you can use `FtpWebRequest`, which supports the ASCII mode. Or you do not want to use deprecated class, and then you cannot use `WebClient` (which [does not support the ASCII mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30946824/850848) anyway).